# Use foreach with Collection object in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I read the doc in https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries which has this line

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->name;
}
```

$users is an object of the Illuminate\Support\Collection class which has $items as its field. So how can they loop through $users which has only one field ( $items ) and stil get all the data of the table?

Comment: You can do the same to your own classes by having them implement [Iterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) or [IteratorAggregate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users Is an object of type Collection. so it contains lists of items of the model user.
If you take a look at the `Illuminate\Support\Collection` class you can see this class implements couple of interfaces `ArrayAccess, Arrayable, Countable, IteratorAggregate, Jsonable, JsonSerializable` And each of them gives the collection class an ability which you can use it. so the reason you can iterate over the collection because the collection is implementing an iterator Interface. so that gives the ability to iterate over them.